SSAS CUBE Import Into Power BI Desktop
I'm new to SSAS Cube data and structures. I'm trying to import the fields I need for a dashboard into Power BI, but I can't shorten my date field in the original request.
I tried filtering the data after I imported what I needed (I.E. I limited the date range to 2023 and 2024), however it still takes forever to refresh on desktop as I build out the visuals.
Further I learned a snippet of MDX to try to pull in what I need and it works for some fields, but when trying to combine fields (calculated and tabulated) I get errors and blanks....
Cannot use Live Connection as it disables as customization in Power BI.
Does anyone know how I can select all the fields I need from CUBE within a specific date range???

I would go for applying the date filtering directly in the SSAS Cube if possible before bringing it into Power BI since you can use row or measure filters in MDX for date restrictions like :
[Date].[Year].&[2023]:[Date].[Year].&[2024].

IMHO, even though Live Connection is off the table, using import mode but with a smaller dataset can be effective if you use incremental load to bring in data progressively, especially for historical data.

Ah I wish I could do that! That would actually solve my problem immediately.
I've requested to have a smaller dataset but the 'lift' would be too much, hence I'm stuck.
What I'm implementing now is a direct IMPORT of very key fields I need into Power Query and then filtering the date I need. (Doesn't help the querying against the Cube)
Secondly using an MDX script to bring in the rest.
Thank you for replying :) This has been a challenging adventure!
